# Amazon SNS Mobile Push - how to bulk create topics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

Is there any way to bulk create topics from AWS SNS Console? Like uploading a CSV file or something of the sort? I have around 250 topics and I'd love to avoid creating them manually one by one.

Comment: What language are you coding in?  This isn't that difficult to do with most of the toolkits.

Comment: I'm using Java8 for my backend app, but a small nodeJs app that can do the job would be great. I'm surprised this action isn't possible from the web console.